Stack Overflow when using Jackson to convert JsonNode to an instance of a specific class
I'm writing a incoming packet deserializer. All incoming packets is encoded in JSON, and its type depends on field "post_type".

If it's "meta_event", there must be a field called "meta_event_type", which can be "lifecycle" or "heartbeat".

If it's "lifecycle", there must be a field called "sub_type", which can be "enable", "disable" or "connect".
If it's "heartbeat", there must be 2 fields called "status" and "interval" (millseconds).


If it's "message_event", ...
Remaining many other situations ...

Here are 2 legal packet strings:
{
  "sub_type": "connect",
  "meta_event_type": "lifecycle",
  "post_type": "meta_event"
}

{
  "meta_event_type": "heartbeat",
  "interval": 5000,
  "status": {
    "good": true,
    ...
  },
  "post_type": "meta_event"
}

I wrote corresponding POJO classes for them, and add a specific deserializers to choose sub-class deserializers based on some fields:
@JsonDeserialize(using = EventDataDeserializer::class)
sealed class EventData {
    abstract val postType: String
}

object EventDataDeserializer : StdDeserializer<EventData>(EventData::class.java) {
    private fun readResolve(): Any = EventDataDeserializer
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): EventData {
        val node = p.readValueAsTree<ObjectNode>()
        val mapper = p.codec as ObjectMapper

        return when (val postType = node.getNotNull(POST_TYPE).asText()) {
            META_EVENT -> node.deserializeTo<MetaEventData>(mapper)
            // ...
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown post type: $postType")
        }
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = MetaEventDataDeserializer::class)
sealed class MetaEventData : EventData() {
    abstract val metaEventType: String
}

data class LifecycleMetaEventData(
    // "meta_event"
    override val postType: String,

    // "lifecycle"
    override val metaEventType: String,

    // "enable", "disable" or "connect"
    @JsonProperty(SUB_TYPE)
    val subType: String
) : MetaEventData()

data class HeartbeatEventData(
    // "meta_event"
    override val postType: String,

    // "heartbeat"
    override val metaEventType: String,

    @JsonProperty(STATUS)
    val status: Any?,

    @JsonProperty(INTERVAL)
    val interval: Long
) : MetaEventData()


object MetaEventDataDeserializer : StdDeserializer<MetaEventData>(MetaEventData::class.java) {
    private fun readResolve(): Any = MetaEventDataDeserializer
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): MetaEventData {
        val node = p.readValueAsTree<ObjectNode>()
        val mapper = p.codec as ObjectMapper

        return when (val subType = node.getNotNull(META_EVENT_TYPE).asText()) {
            LIFECYCLE -> node.deserializeTo<LifecycleMetaEventData>(mapper)
            HEARTBEAT -> node.deserializeTo<HeartbeatEventData>(mapper)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected sub type: $subType")
        }
    }
}

Functions getNotNull and deserializeTo<T> are some useful extension methods:
fun JsonNode.getOptionalNullable(key: String) = get(key)

fun JsonNode.getOptionalNotNull(key: String) = when (this) {
    is ObjectNode -> {
        val result = get(key)
        if (result === null && contains(key)) {
            throw NullPointerException("The value of key '$key' is null.")
        }
        result
    }

    else -> throw IllegalStateException("The node is not an object node.")
}

fun JsonNode.getNullable(key: String) = when (this) {
    is ObjectNode -> {
        val result = get(key)
        if (result === null && !contains(key)) {
            throw NoSuchElementException("The value of key '$key' doesn't present.")
        }
        result
    }

    else -> throw IllegalStateException("The node is not an object node.")
}

fun JsonNode.getNotNull(key: String) =
    getOptionalNotNull(key) ?: throw NullPointerException("The value of key '$key' is null.")

fun <T> JsonNode.deserializeTo(objectMapper: ObjectMapper, type: TypeReference<T>) = objectMapper.convertValue(this, type)

inline fun <reified T> JsonNode.deserializeTo(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) = deserializeTo(objectMapper, object : TypeReference<T>() {})

But StackOverflowError will be thrown when deserializing the first example json, because in MetaEventDataDeserializer, LIFECYCLE -> node.deserializeTo<LifecycleMetaEventData>(mapper) will make Jackson use MetaEventDataDeserializer to deserialize the node, instead of the default deserializer of LifecycleMetaEventData.
How to solve it gracefully?

I have removed the [tag:java] tag as the code here looks to be mainly Kotlin.

How can the second "legal" packet string be legal with the "..." in the middle? ;)

@UlrichEckhardt I assume OP was indicating that some (sensitive and/or irrelevant) content has been omitted, just as in the question text.
